# Group matrix values into separate matrices based on values of another matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I am reading in images with imread which results in 768x1024x3 matrix with R,G,B values of each pixel.

I have a function that takes in an image and returns matrix of segment labels for each pixel so this matrix is 768x1024. the labels are just numbers 1,2,3,4 depending on how many different segments the function finds.

Now I want to calculate the average Red, Green and Blue value in each segment of the image. So I want to use the indices from the segment label matrix to find group all R,G,B values into separate arrays and then be able to calculate the mean.

Is there any smart way to do this? use the indices of each 1 value in the segment matrix to get the values from the imread matrix and group the segments into different arrays? I though of using for loops and brute force through this but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: See my edited answer, sorry for the first one, I was cleaning my keyboard and the answer shot by itself.

Comment: No problem! I was able to use the first answer to make fairly clean solution but your edited answer is great, thanks!

Comment: @endif Would be interesting to know if other solutions posted here including mine worked for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** to handle all channels at once.

Let `img` be your RGB image and `labels` the labels array.

You can mask the RGB image with the labels like this:

```
% create a 3-channels mask:
labelsRGB=repmat(labels, 1, 1, 3);

Segment1=img.*(labelsRGB==1);
```

The average values in the segment labeled as 1 is then:

```
avg=mean(mean(Segment1, 1), 2);
```

Get the average for re in `avg(1)`, the average for green in `avg(2)`, etc.

Idem for the other segments.

Comment: @Jigg and *someone* did! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code that you will get you everything without looping.

**Code**

```
%// img is your input RGB image (NxMx3)
%// L is your label matrix (NxM)

t1 = bsxfun(@eq,L,permute(unique(L),[3 2 1]));
t2 = bsxfun(@times,permute(img,[ 1 2 4 3]),t1);
t2(t2==0)=nan;
out = squeeze(nanmean(nanmean(t2))) 

%// out is the desired output matrix that is (NLx3), 
%// where NL is the number of labels. Thus, the mean of labels is
%// along the rows and the corresponding values for R, G and B are in the three
%// columns of it.
```

**Explanation**

Let's test out with some random values for `img` -

```
img = randi(9,3,4,3)
```

Giving us -

```
img(:,:,1) =
     9     7     5     3
     7     7     2     4
     1     6     7     9
img(:,:,2) =
     8     6     6     4
     4     9     3     9
     3     9     8     1
img(:,:,3) =
     5     4     4     5
     7     2     5     3
     2     3     1     3
```

Some assumed values for `L` that goes from `1` to `8`

```
L = [1 3 3 4;
     4 5 8 8;
     5 6 7 2]
```

The code output is -

```
out =
     9     8     5
     9     1     3
     6     6     4
     5     4     6
     4     6     2
     6     9     3
     7     8     1
     3     6     4
```

Let's see how to make sense of the output.

Looking at the input, let's choose the label `8`, which is at locations  `(2nd row,3rd col)` and `(2nd row,4th col)`. The corresponding `R` values at these locations in `img` are `[2 4]`, and thus the `R` *mean/average* value must be **`3`**. Similarly for `G` it must be from `[3 9]`, that is **`6`** and again for `B` would be from `[5 3]`, that is **`4`**.

Let's look at the `8th` row of `out` that represents the `label-8`, we have **`[3 6 4]`**, which are the mean values as calculated earlier. Similarly other mean values could be interpreted from `out`.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a general alternative.
In this case you do not need to loop over the different segments to get the average of each.

```
%simulated image and label
img=rand(10,12,3);
labeled=[ones(10,3),ones(10,3)*2,ones(10,3)*3,ones(10,3)*4];

% actual code for the mean
red_mean = regionprops(labeled, img(:,:,1), 'MeanIntensity')
```